# disable click and add a class to tag on basis of certain value

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, jstl

I want to disable click and add a class to tag on basis of certain value.

```
<c:forEach var="data" items="${actionBean.empList }" varStatus="loop">
  <c:set var="marks" value="${actionBean.marks}"</c:set> 
  <tr onclick="details('${ data.empId }');">
      <td>${ data.name }</td>
     <td>${ data.marks }</td>
 </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

on the basis of value for marks i want to disable click of tr tag and add a class to tr tag.

I want to grey out record where marks is less than say 10 and user is not able to click that now to see next page.

Comment: For which case you want to do that?

Comment: If you want to use JavaScript for this, you may want to post HTML rather than...whatever that scripting language is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the jstl `<c:choose>` tag like this,

```
<c:forEach var="data" items="${actionBean.empList }" varStatus="loop">
  <c:set var="marks" value="${actionBean.marks}"</c:set> 
  <c:choose>
    <c:when test="your condition?">
      <tr class="yourClass"></tr>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
      <tr onclick="details('${ data.empId }');"></tr>
    </c:otherwise>
  </c:choose>

</c:forEach>
```

In the above code, the `<c:when>` block will be executed if the condition is true. You can add multiple `<c:when>` tags if you want to add more conditions. If all `<c:when>` are false then by default `<c:otherwise>` will be executed.